# UnHex a value Or Column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
select hex(28) from dual; -- 1C
select unhex(1C) from dual; -- Error 1054 : Unknown Column '1C'
```

What should i use in MySQL to Unhex to achieve the result in a decimal value 28 ?

My End Goal is to perform a OR operation, so am trying :

```
select b'(binary(unhex(1C))' | b'(binary(unhex(F))' from dual; -- Error 1064
```

How do i achive the above statement ?

Comment: Have you read the manual section titled [Hexadecimal Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/hexadecimal-literals.html)?

Comment: I tried the select unhex('1C'); as well, it is giving a blank result.  Only select conv('1C',16,10); seems to work !

Comment: So then you've *not* read the manual section to which I linked above?  Don't you think perhaps you should?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Can anyone help me with select b'(binary(unhex(1C))' | b'(binary(unhex(F))' from dual;   ! i tried select conv('F',16,2) | conv('1C',16,2) from dual; Its not working. Is there a way to perform this operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented under [Hexadecimal Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/hexadecimal-literals.html):

> MySQL supports hexadecimal values, written using `X'val'`, `x'val'`, or `0xval` format, where ***`val`*** contains hexadecimal digits (`0..9`, `A..F)`. Lettercase of the digits does not matter. For values written using `X'val'` or `x'val'` format, ***`val`*** must contain an even number of digits. For values written using `0xval` syntax, values that contain an odd number of digits are treated as having an extra leading `0`. For example, `0x0a` and `0xaaa` are interpreted as `0x0a` and `0x0aaa`.
>
> In numeric contexts, hexadecimal values act like integers (64-bit precision). In string contexts, they act like binary strings, where each pair of hex digits is converted to a character:

So:

```
SELECT 0x1c | 0xf
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/60072/0).